# CSS Breaking over SSL

Tags: html, css, ssl, https

My static website has broken css and possibly js over https only. http works fine.
I know the issues of loading mixed content, however most of my style sheets are relative.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/magnific-popup.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/font-awesome/css/fontawesome-all.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600">
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Next thing to try: use the developer tools in your web browser of choice, specifically the Network tab to see if the files are getting loaded correctly and if not, what the error is. If loading is OK, maybe there are some general errors visible in the Console, so look there as well.

Comment: The snipped you provide is not sufficient to reproduce the problem you describe.